# Develop application on a SharePoint 2019 dev server for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a production server running SharePoint 2013.  Can I setup a dev machine with SharePoint 2019 so that I can reference Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll and make calls from there to the 2013 installation?

I'm just looking to manipulate lists.

Comment: Probably a good idea to explain why you want to use 2019 for dev but 2013 for prod first.

Comment: @gregW Same reasons I would prefer to develop command line programs in Windows 10 instead of Windows 95.

Comment: But you wouldn’t be developing windows 95 command line progs in Win 10 as they’re different.  In this case, the dlls aren’t exactly the same (hence why there are different packages for SharePoint PnP for 2013, 2016, etc.  if you were making pure REST calls, that’d be different but you’re using CSOM.

Comment: @GregW Does one develop iPhone apps on an iPhone?  No.  Can you develop a Windows 7 application on Windows 10. Yes.  I'm looking to have a dev box setup for the future and the current state.

Comment: But do you setup your dev machine for the iPhone with the latest SDK for iOS 12 and develop for the iPhone 4 with iOS 5?

Where are you planning on running this code?  Client-side or server-side?  As in CSOM or SSOM?  If the latter, the DLLs will only work against the same version of SharePoint.  You can certainly grab the SSOM dlls from a working SharePoint 2013 install and reference them locally to build/compile but you can't use that against a SP2019 server for testing.

Comment: Sorry.  Leaving my previous comment there for reference.  You "may" be able to do it (as WSPs from SharePoint 2013 will work in 2019, with caveats around referencing tech that's been removed) but YMMV.

Comment: @GregW I'm just looking to query and alter lists in a simple manner.  It's a lot of hoops to jump through to connect to a list like a data table/array.

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using CSOM?